# Anyone else having a problem with Twilio SMS messages are being flagged by the carrier?

Tags: twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

Message filtered
Possible Causes
Your message was identified as spam or unwanted messaging by Twilio's message filtering system
Your message was flagged as objectionable and blocked by a wireless carrier

Also Twilio showing that SMS status is not green right now
https://status.twilio.com/
PROGRAMMABLE MESSAGING
SMS